# Laravel Many to Many Relationship mixes up id's in insert

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got the the problem, that the id's of the FK's for my pivot table get mixed up before insert and thus I get an error because a category with an ID that high isn't available.

Here's how I try to insert:

```php
$newAdvertisement = new Advertisement();

$newAdvertisement->name = $request->name;
$newAdvertisement->save();
$newAdvertisement->advertisementCategories()->attach($request->selectedCategory);
```

The Advertisement migration and class function:

```php
public function advertisementCategories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        AdvertisementCategory::class, 
        'advertisement2advCategory',
        'advertisementCategory_id',
        'advertisement_id'
    );
}
```

```php
//Advertisement
Schema::create('advertisement', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name')->default('');
});
```

And here the category class function and migration:

```php
public function advertisements(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Advertisement::class,
        'advertisement2advCategory',
        'advertisement_id',
        'advertisementCategory_id'
    );
}
```

```php
Schema::create('advertisement2advCategory', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('advertisement_id');
    $table->foreign('advertisement_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('advertisement')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreignId('advertisementCategory_id');
    $table->foreign('advertisementCategory_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('advertisementCategory')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

In the error message you can clearly see, that the advertisement_id and advertisementCategory_id get mixed up...
In this example an advertisement with the ID 19 has been created and the selected category (that exists) has ID 4, but the generated sql is trying to insert an advertisement with id 4 and a cagetory with id 19. Just How?

I'm using the latest version of laravel and php 8.1.1

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`umarketdb`.`advertisement2advCategory`, CONSTRAINT `advertisement2advcategory_advertisementcategory_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`advertisementCategory_id`) REFERENCES `advertisementCategory` (`i) (SQL: insert into` advertisement2advCategory `(`advertisementCategory_id`,` advertisement_id`) values (19, 4))

Comment: btw, you don't use `foreignId` and `foreign` for the same field ... `foreignId` creates the actual field and creates the foreign reference

Comment: thanks, removed the foreignId thing. Never got any errors about that, but this makes it more readable. @lagbox

Comment: you have the foreign keys backwards for the `belongsToMany` calls, switch the 3rd and 4th arguments

Comment: in the documentation it sais: belongsToMany(related, table, foreignPivotKey, relatedPivotKey); As I understand this, I'm using the right order. @lagbox

Comment: right but you are misinterpreting what those mean, you have them backwards ... no you do not have them in the right order  ... "The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to"

Comment: @lagbox it works! thank you. I think i need some more time to get comfortable with php and laravel

Comment: you are probably fine, this one in particular is confusing the way the arguments are named .... i have to read the docs every time if i am overriding the conventions for this type of relationship ... good luck and have fun with Laravel

Comment: @DaNeubi if you check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure), you will see you have your `id`s inverted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the 3rd and 4th arguments to `belongsToMany`. It is a little confusing with how things are named but as per the documentation:

> "The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to." - [Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Many to Many - Model Structure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure)

So, if you are defining a relationship on the Category model to Advertisement lets say then the 3rd argument is the foreign key that references `categories` (`category_id`). The 4th argument is the foreign key that references the other model/table `advertisements` (`advertisement_id`).